# Adding dynamic form for one to many relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

**Background**

I am trying to create a Hypothetical shop where I can add/update a *Customer* and the *Items* purchased. My target was to make the *Items* a dynamical list as the customer can pick anything at any time.

I created two classes:
`Items`, `ItemList` as:

```
public class Item {
    private String itemName;
    private String amount;
    private String quantity;
```

And

```
public class ItemList{
    private List<Item>;
```

The JSP page was

```
<input type = "text" name = "items[0].itemName"/>
<input type = "text" name = "items[0].amount"/>
<input type = "text" name = "items[0].quantity"/>

<input type = "text" name = "items[1].itemName"/>
<input type = "text" name = "items[1].amount"/>
<input type = "text" name = "items[1].quantity"/>
```

Hard coded for getting two items only for now.

In my controller,

```
@RequestMapping("/AddBill.view")
public String addBill(@ModelAttribute("items") Item item){
    System.out.println(item);
    return "NewBill";
}
```

This used to get me the details in the form. Now I was thinking of adding customer details to it so that I can correlate the data.

I tried adding a name field to `ItemList` class, but got null while rendering. I tried putting `ItemList` to a new class called `Customer` with a field name in it.

*Problem:* Please tell me how to make a part of the form dynamic while few of the items will be entered only once.

**Update:**

The form I want to use is close to:

```
<input type = "text" name = "customerName"/>
<input type = "text" name = "customerContact"/>

<input type = "text" name = "items[0].itemName"/>
<input type = "text" name = "items[0].amount"/>
<input type = "text" name = "items[0].quantity"/>

<input type = "text" name = "items[1].itemName"/>
<input type = "text" name = "items[1].amount"/>
<input type = "text" name = "items[1].quantity"/>
```

Please tell me how to map this with an entity. I am not able to map it in Spring. Getting Null for the values in entity. Please tell me what would be a correct entity for the above JSP?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mistake in the code.

```
@RequestMapping("/AddBill.view")
public String addBill(@ModelAttribute("items") Item item){
    System.out.println(item);
    return "NewBill";
}
```

After going through [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html), I got how spring does a binding. A summary would be:

Expression  Explanation

```
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Expression  |Explanation                                                                    |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|name        |Indicates the property name corresponding to the methods getName() or isName() |
|            |and setName(..)                                                                |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
|account.name|  Indicates the nested property name of the property account corresponding e.g.|
|            |to the methods getAccount().setName() or getAccount().getName()                |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|account[2]  |Indicates the third element of the indexed property account. Indexed properties| 
|            |can be of type array, list or other naturally ordered collection               |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|account[key]|Indicates the value of the map entry indexed by the key of the Map property    |
|            |account                                                                        |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After reading this, I fixed the submission my matching the parameter names to the name of the input fields.

Answer (score 1):

When you are talking about the dynamic content, it is simple to construct.

1.) Part of form which is entered once like capturing `Customer Name` etc., will say appear in one section.

2.) Part of form which is sort of `collection`, say `itemList` which customer can increase by adding new, so it will be sort of `grid/table` structure with `+ and -` buttons, to add a new row or delete any row. You just need to maintain the index of the list, everytime user add a new row, increement the index, and if user deletes the row, maintain accordingly.

Spring will map this list accordingly.

Comment: I am having problem with the Mapping of spring. Can you please provide a sample.

Comment: Yes Ankur, my hardcoded code is working. I am trying to add few more fields to it.

Comment: I have updated my question with my exact requirement. Please look into the updated section.